# Maximum execution time exceeded (PHP)

Tags: php, xor

im getting this error, and i don't know why.

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in E:\web\autoopti\thanks.php on line 65
```

The code I have for the PHP script is:

```
<?php
    $key = 129;

    $email = $_REQUEST["payer_email"];
    $first = $_REQUEST["first_name"];
    $last = $_REQUEST["last_name"];
    $acode = $_REQUEST["hash"];

    $txt = $email . "|" . $email . "|" . $first . "|" . $last . "|" . $acode;
    $outtxt = '';

    for($i=0;$i<strlen($txt);)
    {
        for($j=o;$j<strlen($key);$j++,$i++)
        {
            $outtxt .= $txt{$i} ^ $key{$j};
        }
    }

    echo "thanks";
?>
```

And the line the error message refers to is:

```
$outtxt .= $txt{$i} ^ $key{$j};
```

So, I'm guessing it's just taking too long for this line of code to do its work. Can somebody please help me fix this?

Thank you

Comment: nope. this line runs very fast.

Comment: It takes 30+ seconds for me. What are you suggesting is the problem?

Comment: Is $j=0 or o? (zero or 'oh')?

Comment: The XOR script was from a website. I t is the letter o. However I don't know if it's meant to be a zero or not.

Answer (score 5):

You have an infinite loop.  `$j` starts at o (which is converted to 'o', since there is no `o` constant), rather than 0, and:

```
$j = 'o';
$j++;
```

results in $j = 'p' (even though `'o' + 1` is 1...)

It continues with $j eventually going from 'z' to 'aa'.  Any non-numeric string is `<` any number, so the inner loop is infinite.

I'm not really sure what the point of the script is.  But it looks like you're trying to do some home-grown encryption or hashing, which is often a mistake.  Look at [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) and [hash](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.hash.php) instead.

EDIT: My initial answer was wrong about the cause of the infinite loop.

Comment: +1 You're right, it was "just" an infinite inner loop. I would also humbly submit that the OP would be better off using a pre-made solution for whatever he's attempting.

Comment: He *does* mention that it was a script off a website. Whether that's a good idea or not is questionable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$key = 129;

$email = $_REQUEST["payer_email"];
$first = $_REQUEST["first_name"];
$last = $_REQUEST["last_name"];
$acode = $_REQUEST["hash"];

$txt = $email . "|" . $email . "|" . $first . "|" . $last . "|" . $acode;
$outtxt = '';

for($i=0;$i<strlen($txt);)
{
    for($j=0;$j<strlen($key);$j++,$i++)
    {
        $outtxt .=  ( $txt{ $i } ^ $key{$j} ) ;
    }
}

echo "thanks";
?>
```

Please see if this is the error fixed or comment me

Comment: You should specify what you have changed as well as why.

Answer (score -1):

There's not much to wonder about here. Your code is taking too long to run. You *can* increase the timeout limit in your PHP config files. I would however recommend that you use the command line PHP interpreter to see where your program is taking all these 30 seconds and then figure out how to optimise it.

Comment: I am using Winhost to host my php, however they do not have any options/config/ or anything to let me do php stuff. So basically what i get is what i get with no modification!

Comment: And yes, I am aware of the irony :)

Comment: just set the time in your script, at the very top:

    set_time_limit(60); // or 0 for "off" (not recommended)

Comment: Done. Fatal Error. Apparently, 60seconds isn't long enough either. Howsa bout we just make it an even 10minutes? :P

Comment: Nonsense. There's probably a problem if it's taking that long. That's what you need to fix. A web page taking 60 seconds to service a single request? Increasing the time limit is not a solution.

Also, why the -1? I hate it when people don't say *why* they don't approve of the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use `set_time_limit(0)` if you want to continue with your code which will ignore any timeout setting in php.ini.

Comment: Better to find out why something is exceeding it's time limit.